# Selected tree node set value into page item in Oracle Apex 5.1.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

This is morshed.

I am facing one problem in Oracle Apex. I want to know how can I create set value in tree node. When I select one tree node, then set value into page item.

So please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

No problem; navigate to tree's Attributes section and check the **selected node page item**:

> Select the page or application item that you wish to hold the selected node value. You can type in the name or pick from the list of available items.
>
> This item is used to save tree state, by holding the value of the last selected node. The value of the selected node can be saved to the selected item via the node link attribute, or via a page process. When the tree is reloaded, the tree is opened to the selected node value.

Shortly:

- create a page item (let's call it `P1_TREE_NODE`
- put that item's name (`P1_TREE_NODE`) into the "selected node page item" property

Comment: Dear Littlefoot,

Thanks your suggestion. Applying this way but dose't work. So may I get demo work space for few times Or details documentation. I created one tree region and two item and i want to set value into two item from tree when i select tree node.

Comment: Text I posted is taken from Apex App. Builder Help section; feel free to locate it in Documentation. I don't quite understand why you'd want to put selected tree node into **two** items; what's wrong with just one? If you create an example on apex.oracle.com, let us know login credentials and someone might try to assist that way.

Comment: 'javascript:$s(''P152_PARENT'','''||ACC_NAME||''')' as link. Here is a single column link. But I want to here is two link column. Is it possible? If possible then how can i solve this?

--'javascript:$s(''P152_ACC_ID'', '''||ACC_ID||''')' as link
  'javascript:$s(''P152_PARENT'','''||ACC_NAME||''')' as link